# Xref table - How to recover PDF file if one of the xref trailer has /prev 0 entry

Tags: parsing, pdf

XRef table at offset 666027 has /Prev entry as 0, which seems to be wrong, how to handle such pdfs, how to get the actual /Prev in such cases? 
Please look into attached pdf http://www.filedropper.com/hackermonthly-issue-11

Comment: Acrobat opens it 'as usual' but wants to save it on closing. This is an indication it "repaired" the file; probably by enumerating the objects in the file and ignoring the `xref` tables. Technically speaking, the file is damaged and there is no right way to "handle" it.

Comment: @Jongware: Elevate your comment into an answer and I'll upvote it.

Answer (score 3):

Acrobat opens it 'as usual' but then wants to save it on closing. This is an indication it "repaired" the file; probably by enumerating the objects in the file and ignoring the xref tables.

Technically speaking, the file is damaged and there is no right way to "handle" it. Opening then saving it with Acrobat may work for some files, but is it not totally fail-safe; Acrobat still has to guess which objects are still valid and which are not.

The PDF was originally created with Adobe InDesign CS5, which is not known to generate faulty PDFs, and one can assume the tool that was used to add the annotations damaged the file. A cursory glance at the end of the file confirms this: the `startxref` offset is off by a couple of bytes, and when fixing this with a hex editor, you will only find the *previous* `startxref` (for another annotation) is *also* off by a couple of bytes – at which point I gave up and did not check further. So whatever tool you used to annotate the PDF, don't use it anymore.